# Stumped by K&R exercise 1.5.2

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am currently trying to learn C by using the K&R, but I am completely stumped by example 1.5.2. For some reason, after I press Ctrl-Z, instead of printing `nc`, it prints `nc` multiplied by 2. I don't know what could be causing this problem (I copied the code exactly how it is in the book). The compiler I am using is Visual Studio 2010. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

long nc;

nc = 0;
while (getchar() != EOF)
    ++nc;
printf("%1d\n", nc);


}
```

Comment: I assume you mean "it prints 2", not "nc multiplied by 2".  I guess the Ctrl+Z is generating 2 keystrokes.

Comment: Because `enter` is a keystroke.

Comment: oh, I see now, so that is why every keystroke was registering twice instead of once.

Comment: Moved to an answer because, well, it is :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I require multiple EOF (CTRL+Z) characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655112/why-do-i-require-multiple-eof-ctrlz-characters)

Comment: @Foo - that has nothing to do with it. He was properly hitting ^Z on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `enter` is a keystroke.

If your input is:

```
1<enter>
1<enter>
1<enter>
^z
```

it would output:

> 6

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you get the behaviour you describe but that should be %ld not %1d

Answer (score 0):

Could not reproduce your error.  I added some debugging statements,

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
     int nc = 0, ch;

     while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
          printf("%d\n", ch);
          ++nc;
     }
     printf("nc - %1d\n", nc);


}
```

And then tried it with `gcc` on Windows:

```
E:\temp>gcc eof.c

E:\temp>a
^Z
nc - 0

E:\temp>a
foo bar
102
111
111
32
98
97
114
10
^Z
nc - 8
```

And then with Visual Studio 2008:

```
E:\temp>cl eof.c
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

eof.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:eof.exe
eof.obj

E:\temp>eof
^Z
nc - 0

E:\temp>eof
foo bar
102
111
111
32
98
97
114
10
^Z
nc - 8
```

Comment: He was hitting `enter` after each letter he typed (resulting in `nc` being twice as large as he expected). See comments.