# Why do I have to type CTRL + Z 3 times to send EOF?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, scanf, eof

```
int x, sum=0;
while(scanf_s("%d", &x) != EOF) 
{
    sum += x;  
}
printf("sum is %d", sum);
return 0;
```

No matter how input ,I must type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> three times to print `sum`. I'm using VS 2015.

Comment: Shouldn't `scanf_s` be used like this (in your case): `scanf_s("%d", &x, 1)`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Nope. The extra argument is required only when using `%c`, `%s` or `%[`.

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] along with the sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: thanks for comments, I find using that code on VS2008, it works. so, there's something wrong in VS2015. also use  `#pragma warning (disable : 4996)` and  `scanf` instad of `scanf_s`, it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I require multiple EOF (CTRL+Z) characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655112/why-do-i-require-multiple-eof-ctrlz-characters)

Answer (score -2):

EOF is a special constant that should only be used when reading from files to check for the end of the file

The **E**nd **O**f the **F**ile is what it represents and is a handy way to represent that without remembering what actual value it is.

Pressing Ctrl + Z causes differing behaviors depending on the system. On Linux systems it suspends a process. On Windows, it is interpreted as the Undo command by the kernel. It has no behavior on Mac OS, and is substituted for CMD + Z, which functions similarly to Windows Ctrl + Z.

`scanf_s` returns an `int` that is the number of characters read from the input.

Comment: Good info, but this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Then post an an "actual" answer instead of complaining about it. He wanted to know why he had to press Ctrl + Z 3 times. My answer is because the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I don't take criticism if it's non-constructive, much like your comment. See my profile for other places where people have corrected me. I take it well if they offer a correct answer instead of just saying, "You're wrong."