# Using ctrl + z to end reading an array of characters in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want `a`, to be read until user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. But it does nothing. My guess is that it's visual studios fault, because when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> it shows `^Z` in console. What should I do? here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[50], b[20];
    int n;
    while (1)
    {
        if (NULL == fgets(a, 50, stdin)) 
            break;
        cin >> b;
        cin >> n;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [How to send EOF via Windows terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136400/how-to-send-eof-via-windows-terminal)

Comment: This is C++ not C. You may want to update the question title.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's the question! ctrl z doesn't work

Comment: Might be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-control-handlers

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261483/why-ctrl-z-does-not-trigger-eof and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655112/why-do-i-require-multiple-eof-ctrlz-characters

Comment: why do you use `fgets` in C++ instead of `std::getline`?

Comment: @phuclv does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

End of file in an interactive terminal does not depend on the language nor on the OS but on... the terminal and the configuration of the command interpretor.

If you use a true console on Windows running the good old `cmd.exe`, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> will be seen as an end of file. If you use an IDE, anything is possible and you should try also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> because some IDE prefere to provide a Unix compatible environment. After all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> was the end of file on CP/M (ancestor of MS/DOS) in the 70'...

Comment: I have to use ctrl + z

Answer (score 0):

I tried `Enter` then `Ctrl Z` then `Enter` then next ... and it worked